# Google Cloud CDN / DNS questions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-cdn

Does google cloud dns support auto renewing wild cards and also, geographic location responses.

How does google CDN map the request to the origin and is there a limit on the number of domains we can use.

Comment: Ask one well defined question per post. 1) DNS is part of the process to issue and renew SSL certificates, but does not manage that process. 2) Clarify what you mean by `map the request` (move to a new question). 3) Yes, there is a limit. Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas). You can have 10,000 zones and 10,000 resource records per zone.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

As answered by @JohnHanley:

> A. DNS is part of the process to issue and renew SSL certificates, but does not manage that process.
>
> B. Yes, there is a limit to the number on the number of domains that can be used . Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas). You can have 10,000 zones and 10,000 resource records per zone.

You may want to clarify what you mean with `map the request` or move it to another question/post.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.